# Why is there a timeout in SqlClient / SqlConnection query (ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader) when using .NET Core, but not .NET regular or SSMS?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to execute the SP using below code in .Net Core

```
using (DBContext context = new DBContext()){
                {
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {

        command.CommandText = "Sp_Name";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@input", SqlDbType.VarChar ,3) { Value = InputValue });
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Return_Value", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3) { Value = string.Empty });

        context.Database.OpenConnection();

        var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var code = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal(""));
        }
    }}
```

The query works fine for some input param but throwing exception for some, example:

**--This scenario working fine in EF Code and SQL**

```
    SP - exec Sp_Name @input = 'PDX',  @Return_Value = ''

    --Result (No Column Name) - '3I9'
```

**-- This scenario not working in EF Code, but working fine in SQL**

```
    SP - exec Sp_Name @input = 'N01',  @Return_Value = ''

    --Result (No Column Name)  - 'WE5'
```

Exception Message

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at Mednax.ReferringPhysician.Data.PdxService.getGPMSCode(String practiceCode) in C:\Work\GIT\ReferringPhysician2\Mednax.ReferringPhysician.WebAPI\Mednax.ReferringPhysician.Data\PdxService.cs:line 971
ClientConnectionId:199f2b1a-cb1b-4752-8632-9f2c54bcefd8
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

SP looks as below:

SP -

```
(
@Input varchar(3),
@Return_Value varchar(3) output
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @Return_Value = NULL

SELECT  TOP 1   @Return_Value = pacl.P_Code
    FROM    TABLEA pacl with (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB rpp with (nolock)
        ON  rpp.Code = pacl.Code
        AND rpp.P_Code = @Input
    WHERE   rpp.P_Code IS NULL
    ORDER BY pacl.P_Code

IF @@Rowcount = 0 SET   @Return_Value = '***'

Select @Return_Value
```

Details inside Targetsite of Exception message:

[image]

Comment: I highly recommend posting the error message and complete stack trace as text instead of an image.  Also why not just use `deatReader.GetString(0)` if you know there's only going to be one column?

Comment: which line is failing? can you at least tell us that? also: since this code doesn't look to involve EF... does it work if you just use `SqlConnection`?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for comment, I have added stack trace details

Comment: Question: what **exactly** is `InputValue`, and what **exactly** does the SP return (what is the column type)?

Comment: @PradeepH we did not want just the stack trace. we wanted the text that is copied if you press "[Copy Exception Details to Clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/)" on the exception popup window.

Comment: @MarcGravell SP is accepting varchar(3) as input value and returns varchar(3).

Comment: @PradeepH what you posted has nothing to do with EF. It's ADO.NET code.

Comment: @PradeepH btw the call stack shows that you called `ExecuteScalar` and yet your code shows a call to `ExecuteReader()`. That's not the code that threw the exception. Post the correct snippet *and the full exception, not the screenshot*. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I get same exception for both reader and scalar

Comment: I'm sorry if you're finding this frustrating, but... I simply can't repro; [here's a gist that I put together](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/1d34f3d4563c1007ba078b31831b6229) - it works fine on .NET Core on Windows. Note I've used *just* ADO.NET - no EF here. Does this gist work for you? (perhaps using your proc, not my dummy that I drop/add)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Added Exception details in post

Comment: With the latest edit: the error you're seeing is a timeout. So... how long does the SQL take?

Comment: I think expanding `.TargetSite` was a big error; the single most important piece of information we need is the `.Message` of the original error - the **topmost** error. If this was a timeout all along... that would be very frustrating.

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried increasing time out till 5 minutes, but ended up with same error. The SP executes without any delay in SQL. Also there is no issue with other parameter 'N01' in code

Comment: @MarcGravell added the topmost error in question above now. but that is not revealing any details other than timeout.

Comment: @PradeepH that sounds like "parameter sniffing", then - a common issue with heavily biased data. Can we perhaps see the SP? Also, note that there are some `SET` options that are (by default) different between .NET and SSMS - this can cause **huge** differences in performance if the `SET` options cause an index to be unusable. For example, a "persisted calculated column" can be hugely susceptible to this problem.

Comment: @PradeepH note: the most common fix to "parameter sniffing" is to [sprinkle some `optimize for` / `unknown` into the query](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/). This won't help if the issue is `SET` mismatches vs indices, though - that needs a different approach.

Comment: "not revealing any details other than timeout" - there are no other details to reveal; a timeout is a timeout is a timeout; it *would* be worth checking `sp_who` / `sp_who2` to see if your SPID is being blocked at the server, but...

Comment: @MarcGravell rewrote code similar to one posted in gist. Again got same error. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @MarcGravell added code of SP above. it is having just Select statement at the end

Comment: Right. So the first and easiest thing to try is the parameter sniffing fix. Try adding `OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN )` to the bottom of the main `select` query (the one that does real work, not the one at the very end), after the `order by`. See if that helps.

Comment: If that doesn't work, the next thing is to look for anything exotic in the tables you're using. As I mentioned earlier, my first hunch would be a "calculated + persisted + indexed" column. They are notorious for `SET` option problems

Comment: @MarcGravell Adding OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) to SP resolved the issue. Thank you very much for the help.  But this issue happening only in .Net Core and not in .Net Framework, mostly some difference in SQLClient Provider between two.

Comment: @PradeepH nope, this is nothing to do with .NET *at all*. I'll explain more in an answer

Comment: (I nuked the duplicate from yesterday; the real conversation is on this one)

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing here appears to be a bad query-plan cache entry due to parameter sniffing, causing a timeout due to a catastrophic query plan. The issue with parameter sniffing is that it generates a query plan based on the **first parameter value** it sees when there is no existing query plan for an operation (that matches the current execution mode). If you have heavily biased data, the query plan generated can be fine for some values, but catastrophic for others. For example, consider the scenario where there are 3 rows with one value and 3 *million* rows with another value. If you generate a query-plan based on the "3 rows" value, it might make decisions optimized for that magnitude - it'll work fine for 3, 30 and probably 300 - but for 3 *million* it could crumble. Likewise in reverse. Here at Stack Overflow, we call this the "Jon Skeet problem": Jon (the #1 user on the users page) has very different data distribution to a brand new 1-rep user, and query plans for Jon are terrible for that 1-rep user, and vice versa.

Fortunately, SQL Server has a query hint for this situation: `OPTIMIZE FOR` / `UNKNOWN`. The simplest usage of this is to add `OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN )` to the affected query; this instructs it to not bias the query plan hugely based on the parameter values seen when generating the query. You can also specify individual parameters if only some of them are problematic (`@userId` for us, for example).

So; why might this work in SSMS (query analyzer) and .NET, but not .NET core? I assume that the problem here is different `SET` options. The [various `SET` options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql) define the execution mode; some of these options can impact query generation, so a separate plan may be needed for two clients with different `SET` options. This means that .NET Core may be effectively hitting a different query-plan cache to .NET, so: when one is working, the other is failing. But: this doesn't mean that one is "worse"; rather, it simply means that one of them *happened to generate a query plan on data that caused a catastrophic plan*. The same problem could have impacted either, at a random time when the plan cache became invalidated for some reason (typically just: gradual data drift) - just as the most awkward user (etc) was using the site. Parameter sniffing issues *do not usually show up immediately* - they strike in the middle of the night 4 days after anyone has deployed anything.